# can long polling be used to monitor enterprise events?

Tags: box-api

I tried the logic of long polling for monitor standard events, and it worked very well. However, I ran into issue when trying to monitor enterprise events.

here is what I did (Access token used here is for co-admin account):

1. initialize long poll to get next_stream_position
   [at this step, I could not specify stream_type=admin_logs in the url, which gave 400 Bad Request back]
2. after getting new_stream_position, I sent OPTIONS request to box for long poll url
   [at this step, I could not specify stream_type=admin_logs, which gave 400 Bad Request back]
3. after getting long poll url, I sent request to the given long poll url, but then never got "new_change" back (some events under some enterprise non-admin account occurred during the waiting time).

However, using the same Access token, I could send request to box by using " curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events?stream_type=admin_logs&limit=10&stream_position=0 -H \"Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN\" ", and got expected events response back.

So, my question is:
is it possible to use the long poll mechanism to real-time-ly monitor enterprise events?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently available.  The enterprise events offer some other features like filterable output, which doesn't work with our long-polling mechanism.